# ERRO: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'

Tags: android, xamarin

Criei um projeto do zero e quando fui compilar está dando esse erro. Já atualizei o SDK do Android e mesmo assim o erro continua. Esta dando em todos os nós do **Style.xml**. O que está acontecendo? É o primeiro compile.
O meu Style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona nos styles:

No `res/values-v21/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

E no `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Matheus, são as referências. Quando comecei o projeto estava ok, mas quando eu instalei a referencia Plugin.FirebasePushNotification, zoou tudo e nem me dei conta, pois estava tudo ok. Vou reinstalar as refe e testar outra vez.

Comment: Tenta votlar para as configurações padrões como eu postei aqui em cima, caso não de tente atualizar o app-compat do projeto

Comment: Matheus, onde eu acrescento isso? Não entendi. Voltou a dar o problema e não tenho mais como atualizar.

Comment: Coloquei os caminhos em cima dos códigos

Comment: Não está funcionando dessa forma. Não sei o que houve.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro é referente ao pacote AppCompat do Xamarin, verifique se a referencia esta correta e caso esteja certo apague a pasta "/obj" que está na raiz do projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como sugerido por [AbdiRahman](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59017/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-theme-appcompat-light), eu resolvi esse problema apagando todo o conteúdo da pasta *C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Xamarin* e então limpando e recompilando a solução novamente no Visual Studio.